# How to get sent and received email information?

Tags: android

I am implementing one application related to mailing sever.

As for my requirment,i want to get information about mail,

No of sent mails and received mails from mobile.

Is it possible to get mail information.

If any one know the solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard API for Mail, but if read the android source code (the version you're interested in) then you can figure it out.

Comment: For the generic Email client, yes.  But realize that the gmail client is not part of AOSP, but rather a proprietary product without published sources.  Also, even having the source code of the Email app will not give you access to its private internal storage, so you cannot determine information unless either it exports that information, you replace the factory version of the app with your own version which exports the information (from anything done with your version, not the original), or you root the device.

Comment: This is a given, it was implied. But thanks for the clarification.

Comment: please give info about..(the version you're interested in).If it is posible how.